# matrix with 'row space = column space', but 'null space $\neq$ left null space'.

Tags: linear-algebra

Would you please give an example of a matrix with row space equal to the column space but null space is not equal to the left nullspace? Or explain why it is not possible?

Thanks

Comment: The row space is a space of row vectors and the column space a space of column vectors. So they cannot be equal (unless the matrix is $1\times 1$). What may be equal, on the other hand, are the column space and the column space of the transpose. Same with null space and left null space. Maybe you have a theorem available that links the concepts of null space, column space, and transpose that you can leverage?

Answer (score 0):

Recall:
`row space` is perpendicular to `null space`
`column space` is perpendicualr to `left null space`

It is given `row space = column space`, so the matrix has to be square singular.

The `null space` contains *every* vector perpendicular to the `row space`.  So when `row space = column space`, all the vectors that are perpendicular to the `column space` span the `null space`.

But all the vectors that are perpendicular to the `column space` is the `left null space`.
So `left null space = null space`

---

As an example consider a $3\times 3$ matrix and say the `row space` is the $x$ axis. Then the `null space` is the entire $yz$ plane.
Since you have `column space= rowspace`, the $yz$ plane which is perpendicular to the `rowspace` is also the `left null space`.

Comment: Thanks Could we say it is impossible to find such a vector since for colspace to be equal to row space m=n this would make m−r=n−r?

Comment: Doesn't look complete. Key thing is that once you have the row space, *everything* that is perpendicular to the row space *is* null space.

Comment: In other words, the null space contains *every* vector that is perpendicular to the row space

Comment: So, any how it is impossible right? You change your answer

Comment: If row space = column space, then null space = left null space. So you can't find a matrix.

Comment: That is a complete answer. Thanks

Comment: Would you please help me with this?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432193/is-a-row-of-a-and-also-in-the-null-space-of-a

Comment: I'm also reviewing linear algebra so if I can I'd love to help you:)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that whenever you have the same column and row space for a matrix $A$, we can express the columns of $A$ with some matrix $M$ utilizing the rows: $MA=A^T$. (Also, both matrices are square.)

Now, if $Ax=0$, then $(MA)x=0$, so that $A^Tx=0$. Which means that $x\in N(A)\rightarrow x\in N(A^T)$. Similarly, we can achieve the other direction.