# is a row of A and also in the null space of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

would you please justify whether this is true or not?

Could v = (1, 0, -1) be a row of A and also in the null space of A? Actually, I had hard time to understand this.

Comment: This isn't hard at all if you knew that row space and null space are perpendicular

Comment: Do you know how to test if two vectors are perpendicular?

Comment: of course. dot product should be zero

Comment: Can you dot the given vector with itself and get a zero?

Comment: of course not but you know we can't answer this question like your explanation

Comment: It seems like you're making me do your homework -.-

Comment: of course not! what do u mean?

Comment: I gave you very good hints and you're asking me to write the complete answer

Comment: So, since row space and null space are perpendicular the vector base of null dot product to the vector base of row space should be zero., But here we have one vecor which does not satisfy the requirement, So, it is not true

Comment: But, I think this might not be completely true. For example, sometimes we have two vector bases then what should we do?

Comment: Not quite. Say  $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}$. Recall that the null space contains all vectors that satisfy $Ax=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$. What is the first component of $A\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Thank you so much but I don't want to make it complicated. You confused me!

Comment: I asked a question..

Comment: The thing you said first means: a vector in both the null space and row space has to be 0  or  if the transpose of a vector in the row space is in the right null space, it must be 0

Comment: Hmm. I'm referring to the question about finding the `first component of...`

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678572/why-a-vector-in-both-the-null-space-and-row-space-has-to-be-0

Comment: That's not the question I asked. I want to help but you seem to be in rush

Comment: No I am not in rush but you made it complicated so ...

Comment: Which part is complicated?

Comment: the answer was there and it is exactly what you said first

Comment: Again wich part is complicated?

Comment: Saying just confusing or complicated doesn't help. You have to be specific

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a matrix $A$ with rows $r_1,r_2,r_3$ such that $r_i=v^T=(1,0,-1)$ for one of the indices,  with the extra property $Av=0$.

However, when calculating this product, we obtain $Av=(r_1v,\,r_2v,\,r_3v)^T$, its $i$th coordinate is $r_iv=v^Tv=2$, so we can't get the null vector.